# Using Yet Another Forum as a Blog

Tags: asp.net, blogs, forums, yetanotherforum

I use YAF with full integration as part of my website's forum page. It works great! I've now decided that I want to start blogging... Can I modify YAF into a blogger for a different section of my site? If not, then what's a recommended ASP.NET based blogging solution, that can also integate fully within my site?

Comment: This is not a programming question, not does it appear to be programming related. Voting to close as off topic.

Comment: @Oded - I disagree. YAF is a .NET/C# forum and modifying it to work as a blog would be a job for a programmer, making it programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't modify YAFF.  There are a bunch of great ASP.NET blogging platforms available for free, and easy to install.  The easiest thing to do is use the Web Platform Installer.  You can see what's available at http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/Categories.aspx?category=Blogs.

If you're going to put a blog in a subfolder under YAFF (or any other .NET app), you'll probably need to do some web.config editing to remove the specific handlers in place from the app in the parent folder.  You don't need to do this if both YAFF and the blog are siblings under a root, and the root app does not add any handlers in the web.config.